# Array within JSON manipulation issues using map method

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, axios

I am building a pokemon wiki-type page as a beginner project. I want to render out the pokemon's types from the json object I am getting via axios. However, I cannot seem to properly use the map method on the types array returned in the object.

Currently, I am trying to set the typesItem const to be the mapped

elements and then just slap that in my list of attributes.
I get this error however Pokemon.jsx:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). So i think the error is in my line 30. and it's almost definitely because I'm messing up how to access certain parts of json objects.

Use this to view the json api https://pokeapi.co/

```
import React from "react";

import axios from "axios";
import "../styles/pokemon.css";

export default function Pokemon() {
  const [inputPokemon, setInputPokemon] = React.useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState({});

  function handleKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.key == "Enter") {
      fetchPokemon();
      setInputPokemon("");
    }
  }

  async function fetchPokemon() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${inputPokemon.toLowerCase()}`
      );

      setResult(response.data);
      //   console.log(response.data);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  const typesItem = result.types.map((item) => <p>{item.type.name}</p>);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="pokemon-input-container">
        <h3>Search for Details about your Favorite Pokemon!</h3>
        <br></br>
        <input
          className="pokemon-input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Input Pokemon Name"
          onChange={(e) => setInputPokemon(e.target.value)}
          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
          value={inputPokemon}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="pokemon-output-container">
        <div className="name">Name: {result.name}</div>
        <div className="type">Type: {typesItem}</div>
        <div className="weight">
          Weight: {result.weight} Height: {result.height}"
        </div>
        <div className="moves">Possible Moves: </div>
        <div className="stats">Stats:</div>
        <div className="abilities">Abilities: </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: `result` starts as an empty object `{}` you need to check that a result has been found / the request for the result has finished before attempting to show information from the result. You get away with things like `result.height` because you don't attempt to do any actions on the undefined value, but when you do `result.types.map(...)` types is undefined so it has no member `map`.

Comment: @JacobSmit How can I check that I have a result? Shouldnt using await effectively not allow my code to proceed until I get a result?

Comment: @JacobSmit I tried to implement useEffect using the result state variable in the dependency array to only make it run when the result variable changes. I thought this would be a solution but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Threw up a brief answer with a snippet, the issue isn't how you are loading data the issue is that you are not waiting for the data to load before attempting to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short on time at the moment, but the below snippet should fix your issue (some comments contained within).

```
import React from "react";

import axios from "axios";
import "../styles/pokemon.css";

export default function Pokemon() {
  const [inputPokemon, setInputPokemon] = React.useState("");
  // use undefined instead of empty object (easier to run conditions on).
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState(undefined);

  function handleKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.key == "Enter") {
      fetchPokemon();
      setInputPokemon("");
    }
  }

  async function fetchPokemon() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${inputPokemon.toLowerCase()}`
      );

      setResult(response.data);
      //   console.log(response.data);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      // When error clear data.
      setResult(undefined);
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="pokemon-input-container">
        <h3>Search for Details about your Favorite Pokemon!</h3>
        <br></br>
        <input
          className="pokemon-input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Input Pokemon Name"
          onChange={(e) => setInputPokemon(e.target.value)}
          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
          value={inputPokemon}
        />
      </div>
      {
        // check if result exists, if you are worried about result being a falsy value
        // that react will display slap two bangs on it (!!result) but if it's either undefined
        // or an object it shouldn't be a problem.
        //
        // Now nothing else will be run on result unless it has been populated, problem solved.
        result && (
          <div className="pokemon-output-container">
            <div className="name">Name: {result.name}</div>
            <div className="type">Type: {result.types.map((item) => <p>{item.type.name}</p>)}</div>
            <div className="weight">
              Weight: {result.weight} Height: {result.height}"
            </div>
            <div className="moves">Possible Moves: </div>
            <div className="stats">Stats:</div>
            <div className="abilities">Abilities: </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. this makes so much sense, I never thought to use the undefined state and then handle it this way. TY!

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this and tell me if it's outputting:

```
useEffect(()=>{
     console.log(result)
},[result])
```

If this is outputting undefined then something is wrong in your Database call

Ok, since there's a result, try this:

```
let typesItem=''
if(results) typesItem = result.types.map((item) => <p>{item.type.name}</p>)
console.log(typesItem)
```

Comment: This is resulting in typesItem not being defined. Assuming this has something to do with the comment above from Jacob.

Comment: I'm thinking now that your code should work. I edited my reply, try that and tell me if the result is printing out

Comment: yes that is logging the full object

Comment: And after I search for a pokemon, and change my react code to get more specific I can get all the way down to the type like I originally wanted. It's just breaking on load when there is no data

Comment: @LearningCoder could you show a sample of the logging result?

Comment: So I changed the useeffect to  ```React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(result.types[0].type.name);
  }, [result]);```. This then returns the word electric. THIS ONLY WORKS if i've already searched for a pokemon and edit the reactjs. On load the website breaks when trying to access the types array elements.

Comment: @LearningCoder you need to give more information. What you mean by breaking?